# getting error in simple spring example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependencies

My spring library : 3.2.0

Xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<bean id = "res_Bean" class = "Restaurant"
<property name="welcomeNote" value="welcome to my restaurant"/>

</bean>

</beans>
```

Im trying to solve , but im not getting correct ans.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:BeanFactory
>   not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing
>   beans via the ApplicationContext  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
>     at TestSpring.main(TestSpring.java:12)

Comment: how about showing the code at `TestSpring.java:12`

Comment: Please show the main method.

Comment: main method code http://ideone.com/SJpSrR

Answer (score 1):

When you define bean attribute class should be equals to full package path of the class.

For example

```
<bean id="restaurant" class="com.models.Restaurant"> 
      <property <property name="welcomeNote" value="welcome to my restaurant"/>>
</bean>
```

Comment: still im getting same error..  see my spring example folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5UqJAjG6ARcYlZNTXA0b0g2VTA?usp=sharing